# How to export 3D model for entire city from Google Earth

Tags: 3d, google-earth

This question has been asked so many times but I simply cannot get a clear answer.

I want to create an animation using all the 3D mapping that Google Earth has represented for downtown Seattle and need to find a way to export this data into a readable 3D format.

Otherwise it's buying something like [this](http://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/3d-model-seattle-cityscape/894482) for the cost of a used car.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Import models of buildings from 3D Warehouse to SketchUp

You will need SketchUp application. SketchUp Make (which is free) is sufficient.

1. Add geo-location to model: `File -> Geo-location -> Add location`.
   Select region (i.e. whole city) and grab it into model.
2. Show terrain: `File -> Geo-location -> Show Terrain`
3. Open 3D Warehouse: `Window -> 3D Warehouse`. Search for buidings from chosen city/area. Download model. Chose Yes when asked if it should be loaded directly into your SketchUp model.

   Downloaded model is located properly in your terrain. Download other models.

### 2. Export model from SketchUp to COLLADA (.dae)

We can export model to [COLLADA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COLLADA). It can be opened in 3ds Max, Blender, Photoshop and many others listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COLLADA). It's just:

`File -> Export -> 3D Model`

Answer (score 0):

do you mean the oblique photography models? You need to find the city models source url. And then use the lrc file to fetch the models.